# Função scanf causando loop infinito

Tags: c

Tenho um código simples que converte um *char* em um *int* dentro de um *loop* *while*, porém quando executo e coloco o primeiro *char*, o programa entra em *loop* infinito, aqui vai o código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   char c;

   while (1)
   {
       printf("Enter a character: ");
       if (scanf("%c", &c) == 0)
           printf("Err");

       printf("The numeric form of %c is %d\n", c, c);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: não é o `scanf` que causa loop infinito, é o próprio `while`. Com `while(1)`  como ele irá sair do loop? 1 nunca vai deixar de ser 1

Answer (score 1):

O código não tem nenhuma condição de parada. Pelo que entendi, você quer sair do *loop* quando o usuário digitar `0`.

```
while (1)
{
   printf("Enter a character: ");
   if (scanf("%c", &c) == 0) {
       printf("Err");
       break;
   }

   printf("The numeric form of %c is %d\n", c, c);
}
```

Uma alternativa simples para isso é, após ser exibida a *mensagem de erro*, você utilizar o comando **[*break*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-BR/library/wt88dxx6.aspx)**, que encerra o *loop* e "*segue o fluxo*", pra encerrar a aplicação.